# Is there a loop or a function in R to reverse calculate marginal taxes?

Tags: r

Need to solve this interdependent variables to find b and c

```
a <- 20000
b <- 10% * c
c <- a + b
```

Cant figure out what to do, stuck on this since a week.

Comment: You don't need anything but algebra. Substitute the right-hand side of the third equation in place of c in the second equation and solve for b (b = a/9).

Comment: Is the question how to solve this system of equations, or how to solve this system of equations *in R*? If it's the first, it should be closed because it's not about programming, and if the second, you should include what you've tried so we know how you're approaching the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algebra is the only thing needed here. Substitute the right-hand side of the third equation in place of `c` in the second equation and solve for `b` (`b <- a/9`).

If you really want to use R to help solve it, pass the system of equations to `solve`.

```
solve(
  rbind(
    c(a = 1, b = 0, c = 0), # coefficients of the first equation
    c(0, -1, 0.1),          # coefficients of the second equation
    c(1, 1, -1)             # coefficients of the third equation
  ),
  c(2e4, 0, 0)              # RHS of the three equations
)
#>         a         b         c 
#> 20000.000  2222.222 22222.222
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.
The general principle is the same as in [jblood94's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74790499/8245406), to solve a system of linear equations. I have set it up differently, it only solves for `b` and `c`, and wrote it as a function.

```r
funSolve <- function(a, rate) {
  lhs <- cbind(b = c(1, -1),     # column vector for `b`
               c = c(-rate, 1))  # column vector for `c`
  rhs <- c(0, a)                 # independent term
  solve(lhs, rhs)
}
funSolve(20000, 0.1)
#>         b         c 
#>  2222.222 22222.222
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>